# Negative loss, 100% accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, data-science-model

I have a very small dataset with 567 images. I've used pretrained model resnet50 in transfer learning. But whenever i fit my model it's giving me 100% accuracy , 100% validation accuracy and in per epoch loss and validation loss goes to negative. The evaluation shows me output with 100% accuracy and -5915788.088888888  loss.This is preety unexpected result. What's the matter ? Is it possible or my model is getting bad output ? I have used the model like below :

```
def Transfer():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ResNet50(include_top = False, pooling = 'avg', weights = 'imagenet'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))

    model.layers[0].trainable = False
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
    model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
return model
```

[image: Acuracy Graph]
[image: Loss Graph]

Answer (score 1):

`categorical_crossentropy` should never be negative. The most common reason it becomes negative is incorrect data encoding. It is best if all features and targets are scaled between 0 and 1.

Comment: Are you certain?  If from_logits is set True, I can get negative values.  And I believe Tensorflow will automatically enable this if you have a softmax at your output.